# Consuming XML from a file/URL without a .xml extension in Flash

Tags: xml, flash

Does flash specifically prevent the consumption of XML from files/URLs without a .xml extension for some reason?
I have verified the output of the URL is valid XML for my purposes but the Flash will not recognise it.

Comment: your content must return a "text/xml" Content TYpe

Answer (score 0):

A few things to think about:

- are you allowed to access this URL from Flash? (security sandbox problems)
- did you convert the result into XML? i.e.

  my_xml = XML( loader.data );